# Calcular média entre resultados do select

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Preciso calcular o tempo médio de reparo para cada aplicação. Sabendo que eu tenho em mãos o código do reparo, código da aplicação e o tempo para cada reparo, qual seria a melhor forma de realizar esse cálculo em SQL?

```
SELECT 
    OS.TAG AS OS,
    APLIC.TAG AS APLICACAO,
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), ROUND(DATEDIFF(SECOND, OS.MAQPAR, OS.MAQFUN)/3600.0, 2)) AS TEMPO_REPARO
FROM [ENGEMAN].[APLIC] AS APLIC
    JOIN [ENGEMAN].[ORDSERV] AS OS ON APLIC.CODAPL = OS.CODAPL
WHERE OS.STATORD != 'C'
    AND OS.MAQPAR IS NOT NULL 
    AND OS.CODFIL = 2
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: SQL SERVER 2012!

Comment: Creio que a função de agregação `avg(tempo_reparo)` juntamente com um `GROUP BY aplicacao` possa ajudá-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode usar a função `AVG` na coluna para calcular a média:

```
SELECT 
    avg(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), ROUND(DATEDIFF(SECOND, OS.MAQPAR, OS.MAQFUN)/3600.0, 2))) AS TEMPO_REPARO
FROM [ENGEMAN].[APLIC] AS APLIC
    JOIN [ENGEMAN].[ORDSERV] AS OS ON APLIC.CODAPL = OS.CODAPL
WHERE OS.STATORD != 'C'
    AND OS.MAQPAR IS NOT NULL 
    AND OS.CODFIL = 2
```

Comment: Essa função só fez repetir o campo TEMPO_REPARO.

Comment: Consegue passar o create da tabela e os inserts pra eu testar aqui?

Comment: Faltou agrupar por APLIC.TAG, AVG funciona acredite :)

Comment: e o perguntador "some".

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT DISTINCT 
        OS.TAG AS OS,
        APLIC.TAG AS APLICACAO,
        AVG(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), ROUND(DATEDIFF(SECOND, OS.MAQPAR, OS.MAQFUN)/3600.0, 2)) OVER(PARTITION BY OS.TAG,APLIC.TAG ) AS MEDIA_TEMPO_REPARO
    FROM [ENGEMAN].[APLIC] AS APLIC
        JOIN [ENGEMAN].[ORDSERV] AS OS ON APLIC.CODAPL = OS.CODAPL
    WHERE OS.STATORD != 'C'
        AND OS.MAQPAR IS NOT NULL 
        AND OS.CODFIL = 2
```